# How do I use a DocuSign in-person signing template using JWT with the C# client library?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have a two role template in DocuSign where the first recipient is set to "need to sign" and the second recipient set to "in person signer".  I'd like to pre-fill the fields and start this template from the c# client under the JWT flow.

If both recipients are set to "need to sign", my code works fine.  Once the second signer is set to "in person" on the template, the API returns "IN_PERSON_SIGNING_HOST_MUST_BE_VALID_USER", yet I don't see a means to assign the host using the TemplateRole class.

This is an example of the working code when both are set to need to sign:

```
TemplateRole propOwnerRole = new TemplateRole();
propOwnerRole.Email = propOwnerEmail;
propOwnerRole.Name = propOwnerName;
propOwnerRole.RoleName = "Property Owner";
propOwnerRole.InPersonSignerName = propOwnerName;
```

What do I need to add to set the host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an In Person Signer, the `Name` & `Email` parameters are for the Host, who must have a DocuSign account.

The `InPersonSignerName` parameter is the actual signer's name. During the In Person Signing session, the signer will have the option of entering their email to have a copy of the document delivered to them.

Comment: Yup!!  That was it.  Thanks for your help.  I think the API documentation is pretty unclear how this works.